# What is the difference between a OEM kernel and a HWE kernel?

Tags: kernel, hardware-enablement-stack, oem

Both kernels seems to include latest drivers, but I can't find why both are needed or what are their differences. It's confusing!

Answer (score 13):

An **OEM kernel** is created by Canonical engineers for specific brand-new hardware that is not yet supported by the (mainline) generic Linux kernel that everybody else uses. OEM is a short-term kernel; users will migrate to the generic Linux kernel when support for that new hardware becomes available.

A [**HWE kernel**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) is used only on LTS releases of Ubuntu. It's simply a newer generic kernel. In fact, it's often the same generic kernel used in the current interim release of Ubuntu. Example: The current HWE kernel for 20.04 is the same kernel used in 21.04.

Comment: Do the OEM kernels include the packages that are put out by hardware manufacturers? A common example would be Lenovo's various Sutton packages, [like this one](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/oem-sutton.newell-aelfwine-meta) 